# Read Hex values Cport Library Delphi

Tags: delphi-xe2, tcomport

I have a problem reading the values from a Comport, is there any solution how to read hex value from comport? I already tried:

```
var
Variable 1 : AnsiString;
begin
 Comport1.Read(variable1,10);
 edit1.text := variable1;
end
```

But comes an error:

> [DCC Warning] SampProj.pas(86): W1057 Implicit string cast from
> 'AnsiString' to 'string'
>
> [DCC Fatal Error] F2039 Could not create output file
> '.\Win32\Debug\Project1.exe'

Comment: How is the data encoded?